# Uncaught illegal access while adding element in array

Tags: javascript, extjs4.2

Here is the `javascript` function:

**Note:** `resultArray` is defined in the calling function as `var resultArray = [];`

```
onAddElement :  function (win,id,resultArray) {
    var controller = this;
    if(!win.flag){
        Ext.MessageBox.show({
           title: 'Yes or No',
           icon: Ext.MessageBox.QUESTION,
           msg: 'Do you want to continue?',
           buttonText: {yes:'YES', no:'NO', cancel:'CANCEL',
           fn: function (me) {
               if(me === 'yes'){
                   ver = win.curVer;
                   resultArray.push({
                        id: id,
                        ver: ver
                    });
                   controller.anotherFunc(win,id);  

               }else if(me === 'no'){
                   ver = win.ver;
                   resultArray.push({
                        id: id,
                        ver: ver
                    });
                   controller.anotherFunc(win,id);  

               }
            }
       });
    }else{
         ver = win.ver;
         resultArray.push({   //getting uncaught illegal access
            id: id,
            ver: ver
        });
         controller.anotherFunc(win,id);    
    }
}
```

I have made comment on line where I am getting `uncaught illegal access` error. I am unable to find root cause of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a solution for it. Just need to define `resultArray` into a function and if needed values from argument array can be assigned to array which is defined into a function.

Here is the modification:

```
onAddElement :  function (win,id,argArray) {
    var resultArray = []; // define array inside a function
    resultArray = argArray; // if required assign arg array to local array.
    var controller = this;
    .
    .
    .
    .
}
```